# Do not show user input in console autocomplete

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Recently, I have noticed that Google Chrome's JavaScript console autocompletes previously inputted commands. For example:

[image: Autocomplete example]

I want to remove this feature because the autocomplete displays variables that may not exist. Is there a way to remove this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A lot of people found it annoying, so they added a setting to disable it.

First, enter the DevTools settings from the menu button in the top right corner.

[image: Enter DevTools settings]

Then, in the "General" section, disable "Autocomplete from history".

[image]

Comment: Ah that's so useful. It was bugging me so much yesterday when I was playing with the console and made typos.